# Run Dataflow Pipeline from Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm executing a Dataflow Pipeline from Google Cloud function and the workflow creation fails with the error shown in the screenshot.

I've created the LauchTemplateParameters according to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/LaunchTemplateParameters), but some parameters are causing errors:

I would like to set the europe-west1-b zone and n1-standard-4 machine type. What I'm missing?

[image]

```
def call_dataflow(dataflow_name):
    service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3')
    gcp_project = 'PROJECT_ID'
    
    template_path = 'TEMPLATE_PATH'
    template_body = {
        'parameters': {
    
        },
        'environment': {
            'workerZone': 'europe-west1-b',
            'subnetwork': 'regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/europe-west1-subnet',
            'network': 'dataflow-network',
            "machineType": 'n1-standard-4',
            'numWorkers': 5,
            'tempLocation': 'TEMP_BUCKET_PATH',
            'ipConfiguration': 'WORKER_IP_PRIVATE'
        },
        'jobName': dataflow_name
    }
    print('series_fulfillment - call_dataflow ' + dataflow_name + ' - lanzando')
    request = service.projects().templates().launch(projectId=gcp_project, gcsPath=template_path, body=template_body)
    response = request.execute()
    return response
```

Comment: This looks like a permission issue from the 403 error. You should try attaching a service account to your pipeline with the correct permissions and try running the job again